# How to refresh Rails / Sprockets to be aware of new manifest on production server after assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, passenger, sprockets, capistrano3

We have a use case where we need to run assets:precompile outside of the deploy/restart process, and therefore preferably without having to restart the Rails server processes.  Is this possible in a Passenger environment?

I've been banging my head trying a bunch of stuff within Rake tasks and fiddling with Rails.application.config.assets stuff, but nothing makes the application pickup the changes to the digests except restarting Passenger with `/usr/bin/env touch ~/project/current/tmp/restart.txt`

Comment: If you're using passenger, can you just `touch /tmp/restart.txt`?

Comment: I should clarify that's the situation I'm trying to avoid when I say "restart the server".  I'll edit the post for clarity.  I'd prefer to be able to just stuff the new assets digest into each of the running instances instead, but I can't think of a way to reliably do that.

Comment: hmm... Just bouncing ideas around, but I wonder if you could update the manifest.yml file, then tell sprockets to refresh it. The manifest will be what tells things like `stylesheet_link_tag` where 'main' would be located.

Comment: Any ideas how to tell sprockets to refresh it?  I tried building a rake task that would loop through the newly created manifest.yml file and plug that in to each according Rails.application.config.assets.digests[file] record, but that didn't do anything, which sort of makes sense since the "sprockets" instance in the rake task isn't going to be the same one running in each of the puppet'ized instances.  I thought about trying to add some sort of flag in redis, but then got caught up on "how do I determine that each instance across every server properly catches the update"

Comment: I got ya. That's a tough one. I came across [this article](http://blog.paracode.com/2013/01/11/asset-pipeline-internals/) Maybe you can hack together livereload, and/or guard to watch the directory. I wish I had a solid answer for you, but seems like a tough problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up going with a 2 part solution:

Part 1 is to setup the app to hit redis to store an 'assets:version' (we just went with a timestamp).  Then, whenever our process was done precompiling, we update this assets version with the latest timestamp.

Part 2 was that we added a `before_filter :check_assets_version` in our main application_controller that all our other controllers inherit from.  This method looks something like this:

```
  def check_assets_version
    @@version ||= 1
    latest_version = get_assets_version # wrapped call to redis to get latest version
    # clear assets cache if current version isn't the same as the latest version from redis
    unless latest_version.blank? || latest_version.to_s == @@version
      @@version = latest_version
      if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.sandbox? || Rails.env.experimental?
        nondev_reset_sprockets
      else
        dev_reset_sprockets @@version
      end
    end
  end
```

And those two reset methods look like this:

```
  def nondev_reset_sprockets
    manifest = YAML.load(File.read(Rails.root.join("public","assets","manifest.yml")))
    manifest.each do |key, value|
      Rails.application.config.assets.digests[key] = value
    end
  end
```

The nondev reset "stuffs" each of the values into memory from the new generated manifest file

```
  def dev_reset_sprockets(version)
    environment = Rails.application.assets
    environment = environment.instance_variable_get('@environment') if environment.is_a?(Sprockets::Index)
    environment.version = version
  end
```

The dev reset just kicks sprockets "version" value so that it thinks (correctly so) it needs to reparse and live recompile the latest assets.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of updating the assets in production is as follows:

```
Rails.application.assets_manifest.instance_eval do
    new_manifest = Sprockets::Manifest.new(manifest.dir, manifest.filename)
    @data = new_manifest.instance_variable_get(:@data)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 4 (Sprockets 2.11), you can do:

```
  Rails.application.assets_manifest = Sprockets::Manifest.new(Rails.env, Rails.application.assets_manifest.path)
  # see sprockets-rails/lib/railtie.rb
  ActionView::Base.assets_manifest = Rails.application.assets_manifest
```

Comment: Is this threadsafe? It seems doubtful. For instance, what happens if this is set in a background job?